# Powershell ISE as Admin does not recognize path that Powershell does

Tags: command-line, powershell

I run this Powershell command in:

```
powershell -command "\\mydrive\apps\automation\install_this.bat" -Verb runas
```

1. Std user, nonelevated Powershell
2. Elevated Powershell
3. Non-elevated Powershell ISE (with F5 "run script")

and it runs successfully but when I run that above line in Powershell ISE as Admin, it complains that it doesn't recognize the path.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> powershell -command "\\mydrive\apps\automation\install_this.bat" -Verb runas

powershell : The system cannot find the path specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ powershell -command "\\mydrive\apps\automation\install_this.bat" - ...
```

So using F5 to "run script" is not the same as the way a one-liner powershell command runs. How do I get around that problem?
It is most advantageous for me to get this to work in PS ISE elevated..
.

.

Here is my path:

```
C:\Users\dabbadoo>echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Users\dabbadoo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

Here is my $env:PSModulePath -split ";"

```
C:\Users\dabbadoo\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
```

And finally, here is the

```
$PROFILE | Get-Member -MemberType noteproperty | select name

Test-Path $Profile.AllUsersAllHosts
Test-Path $Profile.AllUsersCurrentHost
Test-Path $Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts
Test-Path $Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost
```

output from PS ISE and PS ISE As Admin (they were same):

```
Name                  
----                  
AllUsersAllHosts      
AllUsersCurrentHost   
CurrentUserAllHosts   
CurrentUserCurrentHost
False
False
False
False
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your PATH system variable.  PowerShell ISE and a PowerShell command prompt use two entirely different profiles.  You should also run `$env:PSModulePath -split ";"` and provide the output.

Comment: `$PROFILE | Get-Member -MemberType noteproperty | select name` will output four PowerShell profiles.  On each of those profiles run `Test-Path $Profile.*` where `*` is one of the names of the profiles.  Since your issue is with PowerShell ISE this should be done within PowerShell ISE.  As with the other information [edit] your question instead of submitting commentary.